# Making an image gallery but why do I have this error?

Tags: php, php-8

I'm having some errors with my file. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Error:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in C:\wamp65\www\Php2\01_gallery.php on line 5

It gives above error when I load the page and the error comes from this line:

```
$arrayImages=glob( pattern: $path."/*.{".$extentions."}", flags: GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: _but why do I have this error?_ -> which error?

Comment: Hi, this is there error I have:                                                                                       
arse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in C:\wamp65\www\Php2\01_gallery.php on line 5

Comment: Is this actual code? As in, you have `pattern:` and `flags:` written in there?

Comment: Well i'm pretty new to this my teacher made a video and I wrote down the code that worked fine for him but i'm having errors for some reason

Comment: try : `$arrayImages=glob( $path."/*.{".$extentions."}", GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: The code from Alive to Die worked, thank you. but now i'm having another problem on line 15 i'll show  the code and error. Code:    $gallery = gallery( path: 'images', extensions: 'jpg'); - Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in C:\wamp65\www\Php2\01_gallery.php on line 15

Comment: so your teacher is using php8 version and you are using <php8

Comment: apparently.....

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the PHP 8 syntax but you are trying to execute this code with PHP 7. This syntax is invalid before PHP 8, so you need to make sure that you are using PHP 8.

[Named arguments](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) were introduced in PHP 8 and they allow you to provide arguments out of order because each argument is named e.g. `pattern: $thisIsMyPattern`.

If you can't use PHP 8 for the moment for some reason then a workaround is to remove the parameter names, which you don't even need in this example.

```
$arrayImages = glob($path."/*.{".$extentions."}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I fixed it already but i'm having another problem in my code could u help me? Code: $gallery = gallery( path: 'images', extensions: 'jpg'); - Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in C:\wamp65\www\Php2\01_gallery.php on line 15 –

Comment: @SmpLife This is the same problem. Read my answer again and either start using PHP 8 or do not use named arguments

Comment: Hmm alright i'll try to find out how to get php 8, thank you for helping me out!